# Can't update ionic cordova / ionic 2

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

```
npm update -g ionic cordova
```

[image: ENONET ERROR]

As title says it won't let update it. I even ran cmd as admin in case I didn't have access to all the files for cordova/node/ionic.
I'm stressing over this because I need to use ionic 2 for college and my ionic is version 2.1.1.

Comment: Can you give some more details about error?

Comment: Same error and [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/1414) same solution ( 5 secs google-search).

Comment: try a fresh install, i.e. npm uninstall -g cordova, npm uninstall -g ionic, then do a fresh npm install -g cordova ionic

Comment: @Blauharley Thanks! This solution was the one. I was able to update to the latest version then.

Comment: Try to use nodeJs command prompt or git command prompt

Answer (score 1):

Remove cordova and ionic completely

```
sudo npm uninstall -g cordova
sudo npm uninstall -g ionic
```

then install again

```
sudo npm install -g ionic cordova
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly update node js

   Clear NPM's cache:

   ```
   sudo npm cache clean -f
   ```

   Install a little helper called 'n'

   ```
   sudo npm install -g n
   ```

   Install latest stable Node.js version

   ```
   sudo n stable
   ```
2. Now Install Ionic

   ```
   npm install -g cordova ionic
   ```
3. Try uninstalling and installing again if not works

Answer (score 0):

Use following command to install latest Ionic and Cordova.
From your log I can see that you are using Windows so you don't required to use sudo command. Just use following command:

```
npm install -g ionic cordova
```

Answer (score 0):

Use nodejs command prompt for update or install ionic version and run your all code using node CMD

Answer (score 0):

> Use Nodejs command prompt

Then use

> npm update -g cordova ionic